# Program with loop will not terminate with CTRL + C

Tags: c, infinite

I have a program that I want to run until interrupted by user pressing CTRL + C. When I press it nothing happens and I can only terminate the program by suspending it and manually killing it after that.

This is the part of the code that needs to run infinitely:

```
while(true) {
    liveOrDie(field);
    printOut(field);
}
```

The first function calculates whether to put 1 or 0 in a two dimensional array and the second one prints it out using a for loop like this:

```
void printOut(int field[38][102]) {
for(int i = 0; i < 38; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 102; j++) {
        if(field[i][j] == 1) {
            cout << "o";
        }
        else {
            cout << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

system("sleep .1");
}
```

Sleep is used so there is enough time to print everything out on the screen before it is cleared.

So, program doesn't terminate by `Ctrl+C`. What may cause this behavior, and how to make the program terminate after `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: try killing using CTRL+Z

Comment: You're probably killing the `system` call to `sleep` instead of your own code - use a proper library call for the sleep instead of shelling out, e.g. `sleep(1)`.

Comment: Is this a Game of Life?

Comment: Yes, it is Game of Life.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I suspect that the user code runs for some small amount of time, say 1 ms, and the sleep process causes the parent process to block for 100 ms, so unless you're very persistent with the <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd> key then the interrupt will most likely be ignored.

You should just replace your call to `system("sleep .1")` with a proper library call, e.g. change:

```
system("sleep .1");
```

to:

```
usleep(100000);  // NB: requires #include <unistd.h>
```

See: [man usleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep).

Comment: I think the command `usleep(1000)` would also work on humans v2.0 onwards

Answer (score 85):

From the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) of `system()` (emphasis/bold mine):

> The `system()` library function uses [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) to create a child process
>     that executes the shell command specified in command using [execl(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html)
>     as follows:
>
> ```
>    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);
> ```
>
> `system()` returns after the command has been completed.
>
> **During execution of the command, SIGCHLD will be blocked, and SIGINT and SIGQUIT will be ignored, in the process that calls `system()`** (these signals will be handled according to their defaults inside the child process that executes *command*).

Which explains your behavior.

Comment: +1 for providing actual documentation. Also, please don't use die.net, it's outdated.

Comment: Updated documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried catching the signal? See the example code below:

```
if (signal (SIGINT, yourFunctionHandler) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        cout << "Error setting the SIGINT handler";
    }

void yourFunctionHandler (int signal)
{
    cout << "Signal " << signal << " received!";
    //do what's needed to kill loop
}
```

In this way you can modify the loop variable as you wish. And as other people suggested, don't use *system()*.

[Signal reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/)

[Small tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Signals.html)

Comment: Thing is, `system` is very likely to override your signal handler (whether it's the default one or your own).

Comment: And that's why I added *don't use system()* :-)